# What can MyPy detect and what can it not?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I just started with MyPy to add more static typing to my python programs. I tried this:

```
import sys

def summe (a: int, b: int):
    print (a + b)    

def main():       
    x: int = 10  
    y: int = 20
    z: str = '30'
    summe (x, y) 
    summe (x, z) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

and this is obviously a type error and crashes at runtime but MyPy says: `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`

Am I doing something wrong, missed some setting? I have Windows 10, Python 3.10, latest MyPy under Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return value is expressed with `->`:

```
#                          -> Return value
def summe (a: int, b: int) -> None:
    print (a + b)


#          -> Return value
def main() -> None:
    x: int = 10
    y: int = 20
    z: str = '30'
    summe (x, y)
    summe (x, z)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood that. But now the line sys.exit(main()) reports an error ""main" does not return a value".

Comment: I see. For mypy a return of None  "does not return a value". Read here the discussion about it: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6549

Comment: Thanks for the link, this shows at least that this is done so on purpose albeit the reason is not given. So I guess the best would be to return an int in case the return value is used by the calling function. I checked sys.exit() doc and for this it would be ok to enter 0 instead of None.

Comment: Yes but https://github.com/gvanrossum dixit.

Comment: dixit ? sorry I don't understand. You mean Guido would not agree with my way?

Comment: Yes. It is latin. Means "he says it, no one can say a different thing".

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` is not being type-checked as you have not annotated it. Add the annotation:

```
def main() -> None:
```

And the second `summe` call will cause a type error as you expect.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I even get 2 errors, another one saying that main returns no value. How can I fix that. Is there a detailed doc on how to set up my files properly for using mypy?